# Making list of dictionary values that correspond to unordered key list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a the dictionary of

```
animals = {'cat': 24, 'dog': 21, 'bird': 16, 'fish': 11}
```

and a list that matches `animal.keys()`, except for the order:

```
messy_animals = ['bird', 'dog', 'fish', 'cat']
```

what would be the easiest way to create a list that contains `animals.values()` in the same order as the `messy_animals` list?

So the expected output would be:

```
messy_animals_counts = [16, 21, 11, 24]
```

I hope it is clear what I want to accomplish.
Thank you and have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a list comprehension:

```
messy_animal_counts = [animals[m] for m in messy_animals]
```

If you don't know that everything in `messy_animals` is also in the dict, you could use `get` instead.

```
messy_animal_counts = [animals.get(m) for m in messy_animals]
```

If you provide a second parameter to the `get` method, you can specify a default (instead of `None`).

This method has time complexity O(N).

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
for x in messy_a:
    for k,v in animals.items():
        if x == k:
            messy_a_counts.append(v)

print(messy_a_counts)
```

Output:

```
[16, 21, 11, 24]
```

Comment: `values = [animals[k] for k in messy_animals]` contains N looksups of O(1) for N animals. Your code does N² things plus an if statement plus bulding a new list by looping - you could shorten yours by breaking from the inner loop but that still would be much worse then the list comp. So no, we do not agree. Sorry

Comment: Sorry, I kind of phrased it wrong. What I wanted to ask is: is this the best way? already assuming there might be a better one. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the built-in function `map` with `dict.get`:

```
list(map(animals.get, messy_animals))
```

output:

```
[16, 21, 11, 24]
```